# AJAX: How to send each form of the body and disable the corresponding buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send each form of the body using ajax. And depending on the return resquest AJAX i need to disable the corresponding button.

 So the questions are:
                1) How to send each form of the body by AJAX?
                2) How to disable the corresponding button depending on returning request AJAX.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var formDates = $('form').serializeArray() //I want to sen each form of body
            $.each(formDates, function () { //This part I dont know how must be
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "file.php",
                    data: formDates,
                    success: function (data) {
                            $("#dates").html(data) //Return a variable called 'condition'
                            if (condition == true) {
                                $("addFavs").prop("disabled", true); //I want disable the button wich correspond to the form I send
                            }
                            if (condition == false) {
                                $("removeFavs").prop("disabled", true); //I want disable the button wich correspond to the form I send
                            }
                        } //End of success de AJAX
                }) //End of ajax request
            }) //End of each 

            //})
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" value="date1" name="name1" />
        <input type="text" value="date2" name="name2" />
        <input type="text" value="date3" name="name3" />
        <button type="button" class="addFavs form-button">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="removeFavs form-button">Remove</button>
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" value="date4" name="name1" />
        <input type="text" value="date5" name="name2" />
        <input type="text" value="date6" name="name3" />
        <button type="button" class="addFavs form-button">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="removeFavs form-button">Remove</button>
    </form>
<span id="dates"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this, I've made following changes in your script:**

-Get all forms instead all form data.

-Used current form reference for submitted current form elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('form'); //Getting all forms 
  $.each(form, function(i, formC) { //This part I dont know how must be
      var formDates = $(formC).serializeArray();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "file.php",
          data: formDates,
          success: function(data) {
              $("#dates").html(data) //Return a variable called 'condition'
              if (condition == true) {
                $(formC).find("addFavs").prop("disabled", true); //I want disable the button wich correspond to the form I send
              }
              if (condition == false) {
                $(formC).find("removeFavs").prop("disabled", true); //I want disable the button wich correspond to the form I send
              }
            } //End of success de AJAX
     });//End of ajax request
});
```

Comment: `try this` isn't an explanation of what was changed and why

Comment: I've added explanation of changes that made in code